# Anyone can me an explanation why this Javascript function cannot give desired result?

Tags: javascript

```js
     function person1(name) {
        var n = name;
        return (function (n) {
            alert(n);
        })(n);
    }

    person1('susan')();
    person1('peter')();
```

The second statement cannot be run, anyone can give me a correct explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`person1('susan')` does not return a function, it returns `undefined`, so you can't call it afterwards - the extra `()` results in the script throwing.

If you want calling `person1` to return a function that, when called, alerts the name, remove the `n` parameter, and return a function that alerts `name` - *but don't call the function*, just `return` it, so the returned function can be called outside:

```js
function person1(name) {
  return () => {
    console.log(name);
  };
}

person1('susan')();
person1('peter')();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code of your function is basically ok but the call `person1` is not. You should omit the brackets after the call. Because your not returning a function back from `person1`. Actually you don't have a return value at all.

```
 function person1(name) {
    var n = name;
    return (function (n) {
        alert(n);
    })(n);
}

person1('susan');
person1('peter');
```

This would work but can be simplified.

Comment: Of course in this case the function could be simplified to `function person1(name) { alert(name); }`

Comment: @FelixKling I'm aware but the question states why it doesn't work. So I reworked the original code to state the issue :-). Also the correct solution for returning a function was already given before I hit the submit button.